# IntelliJ creating jar file instead of exe file

Tags: java, intellij-idea, javafx

I am willing to build an exe for my JavaFX application. I am using IntelliJ IDEA to do this. I have created an artifact with native build 'exe'.

But when I am building the artifact, IntelliJ creating a jar file (Which either can't run) instead of exe file.

If this is not the way, then how can I build my exe ??

Someone help.

Edit:
When I try to run the jar it has created, I am getting below error

> Error: Could not find or load main class sample.Main Caused by:
> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javafx/application/Application

EDIT: Found the problem

> Java FX Packager: Detected [iscc.exe] version 0 but version 5 is
> required. Java FX Packager: Bundler EXE Installer skipped because of a
> configuration problem: Can not find Inno Setup Compiler (iscc.exe).
> Java FX Packager: Advice to fix:   Download Inno Setup 5 or later from
> http://www.jrsoftware.org and add it to the PATH.

**SOLUTION:**
Install Inno Setup from http://www.jrsoftware.org

Comment: best way is: don't. A jar is an executable on it's own. All you achieve by creating an exe (in over 90% of cases) is you limit it's use to a Microsoft environment

Comment: Unfortunately I have to. :(

Comment: I think it has some problem of 

Error: Could not find or load main class sample.Main
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javafx/application/Application

Comment: that means not all the libraries you need are on your classpath, that won't be magically solved if you turn it into an exe

Comment: Please try to set "Native Bundle: all" instead of just "exe".

Comment: When I set native bundle all, I am getting jar file as well as a folder with a bunch of file. Which includes an exe as well. But that exe is not running.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to build a .exe from your jar you will need to use a tool like JPackage or launch4j (no experience with this). https://www.baeldung.com/java14-jpackage
http://launch4j.sourceforge.net/